# Slowdown in sliding background with Libgdx

Tags: android, textures, libgdx

I´m new with libgx and i have a basic question. I want an background like an image that repeats indefinetely, and moves down. I did with 2 images and it worked, but the problem is that is very slow. I stored the images with 512x512px. My code is very simple but i dont know what im doing wrong.

```
public void render() {
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   offset -= 600 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
   offset = offset % 512;
   camera.update();
   batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
   batch.begin();
   batch.draw(backgroundImage, 0, offset);
   batch.draw(backgroundImage, 0, offset + 512);
   batch.draw(bucketImage, 0, offset + 1024);
   batch.end();
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you seeing a slowdown in the scrolling, or the app itself?

Comment: @Thebluefish Good point. You may want to add some sort of box that moves back and forth so that you can see if it is actually the app that is lagging or just the background.

Comment: Thaks for the answers! I created a project only with the scrolling backgrownd to be sure that the background is the problem and it works slow, sometimes I got 30 fps.

Comment: If your background image covers the entire screen then you should remove the `glClear()` call as it is just wasting time. Filling the entire screen with a background image is the exact same thing as clearing (i.e. every pixel is overwritten every frame, just with bitmap data instead of a single color).

Comment: Yes, Its true, but removing that line still slow.